# How to keep orders in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

In my MongoDB document I have object like this

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 52a46b44aabacb5c218b4567
)
[results] => Array (
    [http://google.com] => Array (
        [position] => 1
        [data] => 42672
    )
    [http://bing.com] => Array (
        [position] => 2
        [data] => 9423
    )
    [http://yandex.com] => Array (
        [position] => 3
        [data] => 5513
    )
)
```

I would like to change data parameter in "bing.com" from 9423 to for instance 300. Moreover, I have to keep order of the sites. It have to looks like this

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 52a46b44aabacb5c218b4567
)
[results] => Array (
    [http://google.com] => Array (
        [position] => 1
        [data] => 42672
    )
    [http://bing.com] => Array (
        [position] => 2
        [data] => 300
    )
    [http://yandex.com] => Array (
        [position] => 3
        [data] => 5513
    )
)
```

Is this achievable in Mongo?

Comment: Yes, it is. Here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.updates.php

Comment: I think you have to work with the positional operator: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-an-element-if-position-is-unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reordering of fields [issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2592) has been fixed as of MongoDB v2.5.2 (2.6 release). Having said that one way you can avoid the issue completely is having results as an array instead of a (sub)document. Also note you should not use "." as part of the key name either.
With 2.4, with the following you will see there is reodering in the case of _id=1 (subdocument) but not in the case of _id=2 (array).

```
$document = array("_id" => 1, "results" => array('http://google.com' => array('position' => 1, 'data' => 42672),
  'http://bing.com' => array('position' => 2, 'data' => 9423),
  'http://yandex.com' => array('position' => 3, 'data' => 5513)));
$coll->insert($document);
$document = array("_id" => 2, "results" => array(array('site' => 'http://google.com', 'data' => 42672),
  array('site' => 'http://bing.com', 'data' => 9423),
  array('site' => 'http://yandex.com', 'data'  => 5513)));
$coll->insert($document);

$coll->update(array("_id" => 1),     array('$set'=>array("results.http://bing.com.data"=>300)));
$coll->update(array("_id" => 2, 'results.site' => 'http://bing.com'), array('$set'=>array('results.$.data'=>300)));
```

Comment: I have installed MongoDB 2.5.2 and after that Mongo is not updating, but pushing data to array.

http://pastebin.com/hJnSDbUF

I suppose that the problem is a "dot" in URL.

Answer (score 1):

I've included examples below using the `mongo` shell for clarity, but the PHP equivalent should be straightforward to work out.

I notice you originally modelled your list of sites as an embedded document, however the order of fields within an embedded document is currently not guaranteed to be preserved so you should instead use an array.

Additionally, you cannot use field names with embedded dots (.) in MongoDB so you should not plan to store urls as field names (see: [Field name restrictions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#field-names)).

In order to find an element in an array you need to search by a value (not a field name) so your schema should look more like:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("52a46b44aabacb5c218b4567"),
    results: [
        {
            site: 'http://google.com',
            position: 1,
            data: 42762
        },
        {
            site: 'http://bing.com',
            position: 2,
            data: 9423
        },
        {
            site: 'http://yandex.com',
            position: 3,
            data: 5513
        }
    ]
}
```

Assuming the array `site` elements are unique, you can use the [positional operator `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-an-element-if-position-is-unknown) to find and update the matching embedded document in place.

For example, to perform your update of the "bing.com" `data` value:

```
db.sites.update(
    // Match criteria
    {
        _id:ObjectId("52a46b44aabacb5c218b4567"),
        'results.site':'http://bing.com'
    },
    // Update
    { $set: {
        'results.$.data': 300 }
    }
)
```

In MongoDB 2.4+ you have the option of [pushing to a sorted array](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/58782996153/push-to-sorted-array) which could also be a useful approach to maintaining your array in sorted order when you add new entries.

It's worth noting that if you plan to store many (i.e. thousands) of items in an array this can impose a significant performance penalty due to document growth and the complexity of updating large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that (as every other DBMS) you can't and should't rely on records orders.

Instead I would advice you to add `index` (on `position`, i.e. `db.people.ensureIndex( { position: 1 } )`) and query your record sorted by that field, i. e.: `db.collection.find().sort( { position: 1 } )`

Comment: I am not sure if I understood well. Is there any way to get object presorted by Mongo? Can you give me some example?

Comment: I think Helid's query returns one document, containing an array that he or she wants to remain sorted

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have to keep urls in their position (If I want to update [data]) and I need everything to be sorted to display results. I could sort this in php and update but it is not as fast as I expect. I would be great if mongo could keep order.